# Horizontal scrollview with images constant height in Unity3D UI - How?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I want to implement scrollview in Unity3D 5 UI with horizontal images downloaded from web, they have **different random aspect ratios**, but I want them to be **constant height**. And width to be according their aspect ratio, like this:

[image]

I tried to use Horizontal Layout Group, but images get too little, so it can all fit in group, when I want them to be constant height and stretch parent's width. So, like, parent's widht is primary and it affects children, but I want children to affect total parent's width (expand it when adding new children images).

Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38479097/4366237

Comment: Hmm, thanks, checking right now...

Answer (score 4):

You need to use ScrollView with horizontal scrolling enabled and vertical scrolling disabled. Setup your hierarchy as in the image below:

[image]

On the GameObject named `Content` attach `Horizontal Layout Group` and `Content Size Fitter` with the following settings:

[image]

Then on all your images attach a `Layout Element` component and during runtime calculate the width using the aspect ratio of the image and height to the `Content` gameobject and assign this width to `Preferred Width` property of `Layout Element` Component: In the following image `300` is the calculated width for the image:

[image]

As a result any images you add as child to the `Content` gameobject will increase their parent's width and also you will be able to scroll horizontally to view all the image.

**p.s.** I wrote this answer in a hurry. Hopefully it will make sense to you if not let me know and I will improve my answer.